# Wrong TypeDescriptor when using JoinColumns in a composite Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've been banging my head around, trying to figure what's wrong with the following mapping. I understand the following mapping is not ideal for ORM, but that's how the database is and I cannot change its structure. I'm using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.0.2.Final.

```
@MappedSuperclass    
public abstract class BaseEntity<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    protected T id;

    @Id
    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Table(name = "campaign")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "campaign_id") )
public class Campaign extends BaseEntity<String> {
    // attributes, getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class CampaignBroadcastPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Campaign campaign;

    @Column(name = "broadcast_date")
    private LocalDate broadcastDate;

    // getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign_broadcast")
public class CampaignBroadcast implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CampaignBroadcastPK id;

    // attributes, getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class CampaignBroadcastProcessPK implements Serializable {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({ 
       @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
       @JoinColumn(name = "broadcast_date", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
    })
    private CampaignBroadcast broadcast;

    @Column(name = "process_date)
    private LocalDate processDate;

    // getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign_broadcast_process")
public class CampaignBroadcastProcess implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CampaignBroadcastProcessPK id;

    // attributes, getters and setters
}
```

---

Besides this structure, I also have a converter to handle LocalDate to `java.sql.Date`, which is annotated with `autoApply=true`.

When I try to load `CampaignBroadcastProcess` through `entityManager.find()`, hibernate tries to convert `campaign_id` to Date, even though it's mapped as a String, causing `java.sql.Date` to throw an `IllegalStateException`, because the String passed to `valueOf` isn't a valid date String.

I'm suspicious Hibernate is mixing up the types of the JoinColumns on `CampaignBroadcastProcessPK`, handling them both as a LocalDate.

Has someone ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but changing the order of the two `@JoinColum` solved the issue. The mapping now is as below:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({ 
    @JoinColumn(name = "broadcast_date", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)     
})
private CampaignBroadcast broadcast;
```

Comment: That's actually what I was saying - misordered implicit mapping. Consider using explicit bindings rather than relying on implicit order coming from the annotations

Comment: No, it wasn't the case, since even with referencedColumnName the mapping didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add explicit **referencedColumnName** to your `@JoinColumn`. The error you described may be due to misordered implicit mapping of composite key columns

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id", referencedColumnName = "campaign_id", ...),
    @JoinColumn(name = "broadcast_date", referencedColumnName = "broadcast_date", ...) })
private CampaignBroadcast broadcast;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because hibernate picked the first data type which was data type and mapped it to Join column